# Allow user for color selection in rshiny plots

Tags: r, plot, shiny

My shinyApp generates boxplots for one continous and one categorical variable.
I would like the user to be able to select the colors of the boxplots.

To do this, the approach was to generate a color picker based on the number of categories of the categorical variable,
and then, select

So far, what I've done is render the colors with a renderUI, and then, allow for the selection in the boxplot function.

However, something is not working properly inside this function `draw_boxplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2, biomarker){`
as this error is prompt in the console.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)
library(bslib)
library(shinybusy) # For busy spinners
library(shinyjs)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # to drop na

# Plots
library(ggplot2)


not_sel <- "Not Selected"


ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    title = "",
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("csv_input", "Select CSV file to import", accept = c(".csv")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable name", choices = c(not_sel)),
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable name", choices = c(not_sel)),
        actionButton("run_button", "Display", icon = icon("play")),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Plot",
            br(),
            plotOutput("sel_graph"),
            br(),
            ### Fluid Row
            #tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-single {visibility: hidden !important;}'))),
            shinyjs::hidden(
              div(
                id = "sliders",
                fluidRow(
                  column(4, div(style = "height:140px"),
                         h4("Select colors"),
                         uiOutput("colors")
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$csv_input)
    #inFile <- input$csv_input
    #read.csv(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  
  
  # Render colors for boxplot
  output$colors <- renderUI({
    #req(input$num_var_2,data_input())
    if (is.null(input$num_var_1) | (input$num_var_1=="Not Selected")) return(NULL)
    df <- data_input()
    uvalues <- unique(df[[input$num_var_1]])
    n <- length(uvalues)
    choices <- as.list(uvalues)
    myorder  <- as.list(1:n)
    mycolors <- list("#727CA3", "#464653", "#638CAE", "#836A61", "#889328", "#F5AF22", "#DF564B", "#6B4A8C", "#CE7EB8")
    nk <- length(mycolors)  ## to repeat colors when there are more bars than the number of colors
    tagList(
      div(br()),
      div(
        lapply(1:n, function(i){
          k <- i %% nk
          if (k==0) k=nk
          pickerInput(paste0("colorvar",i),
                      label = paste0(uvalues[i], ": " ),
                      choices = list(# DisplayOrder = myorder,
                        FillColor = mycolors),
                      selected = list( i, mycolors[[k]]),
                      multiple = T,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })
      )
    )
  })

  ## Obtain plots dynamically -----------------------
  draw_boxplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2, biomarker){
    n <- length(unique(data_input()[, input$num_var_1()]))
    val <- list()
    myvaluesx <- lapply(1:n, function(i) {
      input[[paste0("colorvar",i)]]
      if (i==1) val <- list(input[[paste0("colorvar",i)]])
      else val <- list(val,input[[paste0("colorvar",i)]])
    })
    
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]], y = .data[[num_var_2]])) +
      geom_boxplot(values = unlist(myvaluesx)) + 
      theme_bw()
  }
  
  ## First we create another dataframe that will be use in the new plot
  data_raw_plot <- reactive({
    req(data_input(), input$num_var_1)
    df <- data_input()
    df
  })

  ## BoxPlot
  plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    req(data_raw_plot())
    draw_boxplot(data_raw_plot(), num_var_1(), num_var_2())
  })
  
  output$sel_graph <- renderPlot({
      plot_1()
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$run_button, {
    shinyjs::show("sliders")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  If the `pickerInput()` is hidden your color selection is null at the beginning and therefore you cannot use the colors in your plot.  In addition, as `multiple = T` from a list of choices, you need to use `input$colorvar1[[1]]` and not `input$colorvar1`.  Full working code:

```
not_sel <- "Not Selected"


ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    title = "",
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("csv_input", "Select CSV file to import", accept = c(".csv")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable name", choices = c(not_sel)),
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable name", choices = c(not_sel)),
        actionButton("run_button", "Display", icon = icon("play")),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Plot",
            br(),
            plotOutput("sel_graph"),
            br(),
            ### Fluid Row
            #tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-single {visibility: hidden !important;}'))),
            #shinyjs::hidden(
              div(
                id = "sliders",
                fluidRow(
                  column(4, div(style = "height:140px"),
                         h4("Select colors"),
                         uiOutput("colors")
                  )
                )
              )
            #)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$csv_input)
    #inFile <- input$csv_input
    #read.csv(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  
  
  # Render colors for boxplot
  output$colors <- renderUI({
    #req(input$num_var_1,data_input())
    if (is.null(input$num_var_1) | (input$num_var_1=="Not Selected")) return(NULL)
    df <- data_input()
    uvalues <- unique(df[[input$num_var_1]])
    n <- length(uvalues)
    choices <- as.list(uvalues)
    myorder  <- as.list(1:n)
    #mycolors <- list("#727CA3", "#464653", "#638CAE", "#836A61", "#889328", "#F5AF22", "#DF564B", "#6B4A8C", "#CE7EB8")
    mycolors <- list("red","blue","green","pink","orange")
    nk <- length(mycolors)  ## to repeat colors when there are more bars than the number of colors
    tagList(
      div(br()),
      div(
        lapply(1:n, function(i){
          k <- i %% nk
          if (k==0) k=nk
          pickerInput(paste0("colorvar",i),
                      label = paste0(uvalues[i], ": " ),
                      choices = list(# DisplayOrder = myorder,
                        FillColor = mycolors),
                      selected = list(mycolors[[k]]),
                      multiple = T,
                      options = list('max-options-group' = 1, `style` = "btn-primary"))
        })
      )
    )
  })
  
  ## Obtain plots dynamically -----------------------
  draw_boxplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2){
    n <- length(unique(data_input()[,num_var_1]))
    
    val <- list()
    myvaluesx <- lapply(1:n, function(i) {
      req(input[[paste0("colorvar",i)]])
      if (i==1) val <- list(input[[paste0("colorvar",i)]])
      else val <- list(val,input[[paste0("colorvar",i)]])
    })
    ggplot(data = data_input(), aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]], y = .data[[num_var_2]]) ) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=.data[[num_var_1]])) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=unlist(myvaluesx)) +
      theme_bw() 
  }
  
  ## First we create another dataframe that will be use in the new plot
  data_raw_plot <- reactive({
    req(data_input(), input$num_var_1)
    df <- data_input()
    df
  })
  
  ## BoxPlot
  plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    req(data_raw_plot(),num_var_1(),num_var_2())
    
    draw_boxplot(data_raw_plot, num_var_1(), num_var_2())
  })
  
  output$sel_graph <- renderPlot({
    plot_1()
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$run_button, {
  #   shinyjs::show("sliders")
  # })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]